# ListLinePlot plots my table, but the table doesn't contain numerical values

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I am trying to export a table of data to file, but the code does not appear to be returning numerical data even though `ListLinePlot` can plot it.
Can you please explain why this is happening and how to export the numerical values?

```
    fun[x_] := c11*(b1*c)^x*(f1*Gamma[-x, b1*d]/Factorial[x]);
    ListLinePlot[
    T4 = Table[{q, fun[q]}, {q, 20, 60}] , PlotMarkers -> Automatic]

    Export["CAP4.mat", {T4}, "Table"]
```

[image]

Entries in CAP4.mat look like

```
{20, (1299513514361520844900058054335267563998082498560000000000000000*
        E^42*Gamma[-20, 82])/44547766263}
```

Comment: Have you restarted the kernel and made sure that it works even then? Your code does not work for me, neither by itself nor inside `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide values for the several constants (`c11`, etc.) in your calculation.

Comment: @Pickett Thank you for spending time on my question .. answer below solved the issue.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for spending time on my question .. I will keep it in mind to give more details from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to export machine real values, you will need ask for them in you computation. Try something like

```
fun[x_] := c11*(b1*c)^x*(f1*Gamma[-x, b1*d]/Factorial[x])
T4 = Table[{q, fun[q]}, {q, 20, 60}] // N;
ListLinePlot[T4, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
Export["CAP4.mat", {T4}, "Table"]
```

This will also increase the speed of `ListLinePlot`.